# Floating second li element

Tags: css

If I have the following

```
<ul class="Tabs_control">
    <li class="boom">
    <li class="boom">
</ul>
```

How can I float the second li element to the left?

Comment: `display:inline` to the 'li' should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Html**

```
 <ul class="Tabs_control">
        <li class="boom"> Item 1 </li>
            <li class="boom">Item 2 </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.boom {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
```

## **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6NJHY/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

`nth-child(2)` should do the trick:

```
.Tabs_control li.boom:nth-child(2) {
    float: left;
}
```